# MUI DataGrid disable row selection on cell click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a `DataGrid` with custom cells, when I click on cell to enter some text, it selects/deselects a row. Can I somehow set selection only on checkbox click?
I tried to do something like this:
`onCellClick={(params, events) => events.stopPropagation()}` but it didn't help.
My example: https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-moon-mg78zx?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `disableSelectionOnClick` props.

Comment: Note that this doesn't prevent the user from selecting with the keyboard (Shift + Space)

Comment: Tried 'disableRowSelectionOnClick' and it worked. It might work on the different version of the DataGrid.

Answer (score 7):

In 6.0> version, use:

```
disableRowSelectionOnClick
```